# Run function when tab is selected - Angular2+NativeScript

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am familiar with Angular, but I'm just starting out learning NativeScript. I have a Tab interface using the Tab Template from the NativeScript library. I want to run a function when my tab is selected but am having trouble figuring it out.

Here is the app.component.html:

```
<TabView [(ngModel)]="tabSelectedIndex" androidTabsPosition="bottom" (selectedIndexChanged)="onSelectedIndexChanged($event)">
    <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Home', iconSource: getIconSource('home')}" name="homeTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Away', iconSource: getIconSource('browse')}" name="awayTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Matchup', iconSource: getIconSource('search')}" name="matchupTab">
    </page-router-outlet>
</TabView>
```

I don't really have anything inside the matchup.component.ts just yet because I haven't been able to figure this out yet.  Here it is though:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { DataService } from "../core/data.service";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: "Matchup",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./matchup.component.html"
})
export class MatchupComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private data: DataService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

    homeTeam: any;
    awayTeam: any;
    isVisible = false;


    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    getTeams() {
        this.homeTeam = this.data.getHomeTeam();
        this.awayTeam = this.data.getAwayTeam();
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to call getTeams() when the tab is selected.

Comment: Does this actually work? It is my understanding that `page-router-outlet` is strictly for use as a top-level element and if you want the same functionality as a component on your page, you should use `router-outlet`.

Comment: Yeah, it works. It switches between all my components. I used this template to get started. https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/tns-template-tab-navigation-ng

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few options you could use here,

1. Inject `Router` in each component and subscribe to changes, execute your function when route matches for the component.
2. Declare a `BehaviorSubject` inside a service which you can inject to any component. On `onSelectedIndexChanged` update the selected index into that `BehaviorSubject`. The child components may subscribe to this `BehaviorSubject` and call appropriate function if the given index matches.
3. `ngrx` can make this even more simpler.
4. You may even inject the AppComponent / TabView into child components constructor and listen to index changes in each component level.
5. You may use the [Injector](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector) to get instance of the component on  `onSelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: Ended up using #2 of this answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `TabView` only keeps the active tab around. This means that each time you select a new tab, that tab's `ngAfterViewInit` will be called.

```
export class MatchupComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.homeTeam = this.data.getHomeTeam();
    this.awayTeam = this.data.getAwayTeam();
  }
}
```

However, depending on your data model, it may be more beneficial to link directly to the service.

```
export class MatchupComponent {
  get homeTeam(): Team {
    return this.data.getHomeTeam();
  }
  get awayTeam(): Team {
    return this.data.getAwayTeam();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not currently using a class modal like your 2nd suggestion. So, I'm not sure I could use that method unless I created one. As for the first, ngAfterViewInit gets called once on the initial load. Unfortunately, it doesn't get called again for every time I select that tab.

Comment: Well, you could just replace `Team` with `any`. I was just attempting to lead you towards classes. ;)

Comment: I appreciate it. I am more than willing to change the tab structure if I need to. I'm just not familiar with how to do that and was wondering if there was another way first.

Answer (score 0):

Would using the `onSelectedIndexChanged` in your app.component like this work?

```
onSelectedIndexChanged(args: SelectedIndexChangedEventData) {

    if (args.newIndex == 0)
        this.homeComponent.init();
    else if (args.newIndex == 1)
        this.awayComponent.init();
    else if (args.newIndex == 2)
        this.matchUpComponent.init();
}
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.matchUpComponent.getTeams')` when trying this method

Comment: you would probably need to import matchUpComponent and add it to your constructor to get access to the functions in it

Comment: I don't think that would still work, those components won't be alive during creation of app component / TabView, it will be in later state.